# Defining a reusable string from within an environment

Tags: environments, enumerate, strings, content-replication

I write documents that rely heavily on the 'enumerate' environment. I'd like to turn any particular item from within that environment into a variable that I can use elsewhere. The idea is to ensure consistency with long headers I have to repeat later.

Ideally, the string store method wouldn't check for special characters like @ or _.
Better still if I could use numbers for the string name.

```
\begin{enumerate}

    (piles of content)  

    \item\label{itm:01} \def\AA{Heading text.} \rAA\

\end{enumerate}

(piles of content)

\rAA
```

This throws an 'undefined' error. It's possible to define the command outside an environment and use it within one, but with extended lists and multiple headers, repeatedly going elsewhere to find out what section I'm in slows my workflow.

Am I overlooking a simple way (or even not-so-simple way) of doing this?

Comment: `\gdef` instead of `\def`? With the usual caveat that this doesn't check for already defined commands.

Answer (score 7):

An environment forms a group, so a `\def` inside it will not survive the end of the envvironment. What you need is `\gdef`, but your `\AA` is a perfect example of something that shouldn't be done, as `\AA` is a font related command (it produces Å).

You can define your own check, using `\@ifdefinable` to check for availability of the command and `\gdef` to globally define the command, so transcending the group structure.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definestring}[2]{\@ifdefinable{#1}{\gdef#1{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definestring}[2]{\@ifdefinable{#1}{\gdef#1{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{itm:01} \definestring\rAA{Heading text.} \rAA
\end{enumerate}

Now we use \rAA

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. You saved a great deal of work, thank you.